# Pyspark: how to make sure your udf doesn't get distributed over different workers

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cluster-computing

I wrote a udf in pyspark that uses a 'for' loop with indices (it's mostly only a few dozen iterations so it doesn't slow my code all that much), and everything the function needs to work is passed to it.

However, sometimes i get an index out of range error and sometimes I don't. (The function basically only works for 50% of the time).

My guess is that this error comes from the fact that the different tasks needed to execute this udf might be distributed among different nodes, which might throw the indices out of order.

Is there a way to tell spark that I want these udf's to be executed on a single worker?

I didn't post my code here because I don't think that it's going to help, its quite complex and many lines.

Hopefully someone has an idea about why this **'index out of range' error only occurs half the time**.

Also, it would be equally helpful if someone could tell me how I could debug it by printing the indices to my screen, or seeing the printed indices on the worker node through Yarn rescource manager.

Kind regards, 
Charles

Comment: You could use `(rdd/df).coalesce(1)`, but do you sure you want this? If a single node can process your entire dataset, why do you need Spark to begin with?

Comment: My dataset is grouped by 2 variables, the function is just iterating over the group, so each node should handle the iteration of an integer number of groups

Comment: mind sharing your (relevant) code?